# Retirar o último espaço de uma variável

Tags: php, string

Por exemplo:

```
$name = 'Fulano De Tal    ';
```

Como retirar esse último espaço, para ficar assim: `(Fulano De Tal)` ?

Comment: Use a função `trim($name)`, ela também retira espaços no início.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Removendo o último espaço em branco**

Para remover o **último espaço**, você precisará primeiro certificar-se que é um espaço em branco. Se for, retornar toda a *string* exceto o último caractere.

```
if (mb_substr($name, -1) === ' ') {
    $name = mb_substr($name, 0, mb_strlen($name)-1);
}
```

Usando as funções `mb_*` para ser seguro perante caracteres multi-bytes. Assim, teríamos:

```
$name = 'Fulano De Tal    ';

 if (mb_substr($name, -1) === ' ') {
    $name = mb_substr($name, 0, mb_strlen($name)-1);
}

echo $name; // 'Fulano De Tal    '
```

**2) Removendo todos os espaços em branco do final**

Porém, com o exemplo que passou, que vai contra o texto da pergunta, você deseja remover **todos os espaços em branco** do final do texto. Para isso, você precisará da função [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rtrim.php):

```
$name = 'Fulano De Tal    ';

$name = rtrim($name);

echo $name;  // 'Fulano de Tal'
```

**3) Removendo todos os espaços em branco tanto do início quanto do final**

E, finalmente, se quer assegurar que não haja **espaços em branco tanto no final do texto quanto do início**, aí sim você faz como colocado nas outras respostas, usando a função `trim`:

```
$name = '     Fulano De Tal    ';

$name = trim($name);

echo $name;  // 'Fulano de Tal'
```

---

É de extrema importância salientar que as funções `trim`, `ltrim` e `rtrim`, por padrão, irão remover quaiquer caracteres listados abaixo:

- " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), um espaço normal.
- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), uma tabulação.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), uma linha nova (line feed).
- "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), um retono de carro.
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), o byte NULL.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), uma tabulação vertical.

Ou seja, fazer `trim("Fulano de Tal\t\n\r\0    ")` também retornaria `"Fulano de Tal"`. Se não for esse o comportamento desejado, você pode indicar manualmente quais são os caracteres que deseja retirar através do segundo parâmetro da função:

```
trim("Fulano de Tal\t\n\r\0    ", " ")  // "Fulano de Tal\t\n\r\0"
```

Comment: +1 - Eu ia comentar justamente sobre isso. O título menciona o último espaço, mas o exemplo remove todos os espaços do final. E a sua resposta foi a única que percebeu isso...

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu percebi isso também, por isso respondi sobre o `rtrim()`

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro O título da pergunta diz "retirar o último espaço" e isso dá a entender que é **somente um** espaço (só o último, mesmo que tenha mais), e `rtrim` não resolve nesse caso. O exemplo dado na pergunta, no entanto, é contraditório com o título (e por isso não dá para saber qual é realmente o objetivo, se o autor da pergunta errou no título ou no exemplo), e essa foi a única resposta que percebeu e mencionou isso...

Comment: @hkotsubo verdade, amigo

Comment: Perfeito, o que funcionou foi: rtrim($name);

Removendo todos os espaços no final! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

utilizando `trim` não resolve?

```
<?php
 echo trim('     Removendo Espaços     '); //Resultado: 'Removendo Espaços'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `trim`, basicamente a função trim retira os espaços em branco existentes antes e depois de uma string.

`trim($name)`

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser remover o espaço em branco apenas do final de uma string, use a função **rtrim()**.

```
'Fulano De Tal    ' //Fulano De Tal//
```

**ltrim()** remove o espaço em branco apenas do início de uma string.

```
'    Fulano De Tal    ' //Fulano De Tal   //
```

Se você deseja remover espaços em branco de ambas as extremidades, então use **trim()**.

```
'    Fulano De Tal    ' //Fulano De Tal//
```

Remova todo o espaço em branco em uma string, substituindo vários caracteres de espaço em branco por um único espaço.

```
<?php

$name = '     Fulano             Fulano Fulano De Tal    Fulano    ';

$resultado = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $name));

print $resultado; //Fulano Fulano Fulano De Tal Fulano//
```